# Why I got "Origin http://127.0.0.1:8090 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." when I access localhost URL via 127.0.0.1 URL?

Tags: http

I started a web app on my local, and access the app via an url with address `127.0.0.1`. But in a function of javascript, it uses `localhost` to do the further operations. Then I got the error
`Origin http://127.0.0.1:8090 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Is there anyone please tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Because the port is part of the domain, and by default you're not allowed to do cross domain access in JavaScript. Have a google for CORS.